# Is there any connection between a failing serialize and unserialize and server configuration?

Tags: php

Is there a condition that force serialize and unserialize block by a certain server configuration? Or is just a server's bad PHP installation?

Has anyone else experienced this situation?

Comment: Please show some code and quote an exact error message or what doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`serialize` and `unserialize` are pretty watertight functions with one notorious exception: If you serialize an object, the class definition of that object must be present when the object is unserialized. Otherwise, you'll end up with broken data.

For any further information, you'll need to add more info.

Comment: my further information will not useful. cause i have to test a script in a remote server where all error message have been strip. i'm testing a script that work in my installation (wordpress). btw, thanks anyway